# How to execute code after reactive table has rendered?

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript, pug

I have a template called `inboxSection`.  In that template I have a [reactive table](https://github.com/aslagle/reactive-table).  The code looks something like this:

```
template(name="inboxSection")
  .col-xs-12.curator-inbox-section-head
    .pull-left
      b {{formattedDate}}
    .pull-right
    +reactiveTable collection=posts settings=settings selector=selector class="curator-inbox-table" rowClass="curator-inbox-table-row"
```

I would like to execute a piece of code after the reactive table renders.  I had tried placing it in the `onCreated` event for `inboxSection` like so:

```
Template.inboxSection.onCreated ->
   # do something with the reactive table...
```

but that doesn't work.  How can I execute some code after the reactive table renders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Template.inboxSection.onRendered ->
```

and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Yes! Why didn't I think of that? Thanks!